# how to properly extend ActionController in rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a Rails plugin (lets call it Foo).
I want it to provide 'bar' **class** function in controllers, so that I can do:

```
class ApplicationController
  bar ...
end
```

`bar` is defined from withing the plugin loading file vendor/plugins/foo/init.rb. Something like

```
class ActionController::Base
  def self.bar
    ...
  end
end
```

The problem is that some other plugins (in my case ResourceController) might load **before** foo and access ApplicationController.

So what happens is that ApplicationController is loaded before the plugin 'foo' and fails since there is no 'bar' defined **YET**.

So ... how do I **properly** make it work works?

I noticed that many other plugins that extend ActionController (for example inherited_resources, resource_controller, ) are doing exactly the same, so it seems its a matter of who loads first to decide if it fails or works.

I know that I can put code in some module and manually add the module to ApplicationController code before calling 'foo'. I'd rather not, I like the cleanliness of just 'foo'.

I also don't want to do a manual 'require'. Plugins are supposed to be auto-loaded all by themselves :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a classic plugin load order problem.  Ryan Daigle had a [nice article](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/9/24/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-specify-plugin-load-order) on this back in 2007. I'll sum up the recommendation here:

```
# in RAILS_ROOT/config/environment.rb:
...
Rails::Initializer.run do |config|
  # load Bar before Foo, then everything else:
  config.plugins = [ :bar, :foo, :all ]
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand,

`ResourceController` loads before plugin `foo` and tries to use the `bar` method you have defined in `foo`. 
Usually, gems and plugins are loaded before application classes. (Take a look at `rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb`). Could you provide a stack-trace of the error so that one can debug this.

Also, for extending the classes, this seems a better alternative to me:

```
module ActionController
  class Base
     class << self
       ... # Class methods here
     end
  ... # Instance methods here
  end
end
```

Comment: not really. ResourceController references ApplicationController which references foo. but "bar" is not YET loaded since plugin "foo" loads AFTER ResourceController